# Array_multisort with multidimensional array and natural ordering

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array

Here is while loop that in my API.

```
while($r = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) { 

$nArray[] = array('bolumismi' => $r['bolumismi'], 'klasor' => $r['klasor'], 'yol' => explode(",", $r['yol']));
}
```

I want to natural sort ordering to `yol` array. I looked into into it i think i need to use `array_multisort` but i cant figure out how? Current JSON output of my array:

```
[
{
    "bolumismi": "",
    "klasor": "114",
    "yol": [
        "mangas\/Gamaran\/114\/0.jpg",
        "mangas\/Gamaran\/114\/019.jpg"
    ]
},
{
    "bolumismi": "",
    "klasor": "113",
    "yol": [
        "mangas\/Gamaran\/113\/0.jpg",
        "mangas\/Gamaran\/113\/1.jpg",
        "mangas\/Gamaran\/113\/10.jpg",
        "mangas\/Gamaran\/113\/11.jpg",
        "mangas\/Gamaran\/113\/12.jpg",
        "mangas\/Gamaran\/113\/13.jpg",
        "mangas\/Gamaran\/113\/14.jpg",
        "mangas\/Gamaran\/113\/15.jpg",
        "mangas\/Gamaran\/113\/16.jpg",
        "mangas\/Gamaran\/113\/17.jpg",
        "mangas\/Gamaran\/113\/18.jpg",
        "mangas\/Gamaran\/113\/2.jpg",
        "mangas\/Gamaran\/113\/3.jpg",
        "mangas\/Gamaran\/113\/4.jpg",
        "mangas\/Gamaran\/113\/5.jpg",
        "mangas\/Gamaran\/113\/6.jpg",
        "mangas\/Gamaran\/113\/7.jpg",
        "mangas\/Gamaran\/113\/8.jpg",
        "mangas\/Gamaran\/113\/9.jpg"
    ]
}
]
```

Comment: `natsort` is quite buggy I think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

would this fix it?

```
while($r = $stmt->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC) ) { 

    $yol = explode(",", $r['yol']);
    natcasesort($yol);

    $nArray[] = array(
        'bolumismi' => $r['bolumismi'], 
        'klasor' => $r['klasor'], 
        'yol' => $yol
    );
}
```

Comment: No, instead my select menu index got all `1` and sorting is not correct.

Comment: are you sure that you've put the explode and natcasesort outside of the definition of the array? Because "yol" => natcasesort($yol) would indeed return 1 (true), because that is te return value of natcasesort.

if so i'm puzzled why its working for me but not for you :)

Comment: Okay your code is correct i got it worked. Thank you.